# get all strings in c# code file

Tags: c#, string, list

We have been asked to provide all of the possible error messages in our code for support purposes.

Unfortunately they are not all located in resource files so I figure that if we can get a list of all of the strings in the app we can then filter out the error messages from there.

Is there anything that would let me do this in a C# app?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have ReSharper 5 you can use their [localization feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html) to help you do this.

Enable localization for your project, then right click the project and select Find Code Issues. It will list all instances of a string hardcoded into the application. (Unless you have `Localizable(false)` set)

Answer (score 7):

How about using the find function like such
[image]

You can also use regular expressions if you have pattern and be detailed in your search by changing the "Use" to "Regular Expressions"

Comment: won't work if the string contains escaped double quotes : `"foo\"bar"`

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: I would say it doesn't matter because the pattern will find all lines containing a string literal (unless you want to do an automatic replace, which I would rather not want to happen).

Answer (score 1):

If you can think of a consistent string that you use on each message line (eg "throw new exception(" or "MessageBox.Show(", it may be as simple as hitting Ctrl+Shift+F in Visual Studio (find in files), typing it in, then copying the results to a file.

Before you jump into Regex land, check this out: [Regex to parse C# source code to find all strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965667/regex-to-parse-c-source-code-to-find-all-strings)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are some RegEx expressions or some such you could run on your code base and *maybe* catch all strings. Seeing as how this is a business requirement and you're likely to be repeating this in the future, I'd refactor to get all my error messages in a structured format first. Then, automate the analysis of the structured format. 
Resource files might be appropriate.